# Android ICS Camera - Frame returned when ref count is already zero

Tags: android, android-camera

I can't seem to get the camera to work on ICS. My original code worked fine in Froyo but now I'm getting this error in ICS:

02-27 11:54:46.781: E/CameraHAL(118): Sending shutter callback
02-27 11:54:46.820: E/CameraHAL(118): Empty Frame Queue
02-27 11:54:46.820: E/CameraHAL(118): Frame returned when ref count is already zero!!
02-27 11:54:46.875: E/CameraHAL(118): Adapter state switch PREVIEW_ACTIVE Invalid Op! event = 0x5

I was wondering if anyone knew what this meant or can point me to a working camera demo that works on ICS and I'll try to figure it out myself. I'm not pasting any code because I'm not even sure where it's happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was caused by stopPreview() for me. Removing it fixed it... but I don't know when I'm supposed to stop the preview now or if it's even necessary.